# Unity3D Character Controller set speed through script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How would I be able to set the speed for going forward and back in the `Void FixedUpdate`? Or is there a better way for doing this? I need to use the character controller though.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterControllerz : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
private CharacterController playerController;

void Start()
{
    playerController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        playerController.Move (Vector3.forward);
        Debug.Log ("RIGHT");
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        playerController.Move (Vector3.back);
        Debug.Log ("LEFT");
    }       

    playerController.Move (Vector3.left);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have only a CharacterController or also a FPC script attached to your GameObject?

Comment: This is what the inspector looks like: http://prntscr.com/a048dt . The Speed float is not being used at all, so don't worry about that.

Comment: Okay, may I ask why you don't use the Unity standard assets (Where a CC and a FPC are included)?

Comment: Is it that hard to use the Character Controller? I just want my character to move left and right when I press the buttons and to always go forward. It's and endless runner. I'll take a look at the standard assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        public float speed = 5f;
        public float jumpStrenght = 8f;
        public float gravity = 20f;
        private Vector3 moveDirections = new Vector3();
        private Vector3 inputs = new Vector3();

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            CharacterController cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            if (cc.isGrounded) 
            {
                if (Input.GetKey("right"))
                    inputs.z = 1;
                if (Input.GetKey("left"))
                    inputs.z = -1;
                if (Input.GetKey("up"))
                    inputs.y = jumpStrenght;
                moveDirections = transform.TransformDirection(inputs.x, 0, inputs.z) * speed;                    
            }

            moveDirections.y = inputs.y - gravity;
            cc.Move(moveDirections * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

I think that's what you want but you may have to switch the axis.

**Edit**: Why is TransformDirection used? Because we want to move the object in a direction which shouldn't be relativ to the object's rotation.

Comment: You should place the GetComponent in the Start so it is done once only. You could also use Input.GetAxis instead of checking right and left (by the way it should be if / else if, if you go left, you won't go right). Finally, your y axis is damped twice since you multiply y value twice by deltaTime. I guess you wanted to blur the track leading to the docs :).

Comment: This is just a sample function and as he uses get key this one uses it too (please read the question before you check the answer).

Comment: Alright, could you explain what TransformDirection does and why is it used here? Why no using transform.forward instead. It is in the FAQ that one should explain his answer. Also, your gravity is not about to be applied since it is only when grounded, the guy is about to fly.

Comment: Should I also explain why I use Vector3 for movement and not Vector2 or why float and not double?....

Comment: Nope, you good now. Took two or three edits but finally you did it. You did not make it on your own tho but fine. You will probably get your reputation reward. Next time, you should just listen when someone is only trying to help you (I was really just trying to improve your answer, I could have downvoted it otherwise) and avoid the smart-ass tone when you clearly display a lack of coding confidence and knowledge. We're all here to help.

Comment: Be free to down vote or answer by yourself but please, don't try to be the smart ass professor who is better than anyone and knows everything